# QEMU config file not found in Freedom Studio

Tags: qemu, riscv

I receive the following error when I try to debug a program in Freedom Studio using the QEMU configuration:

```
C:\[...]\freedomstudio\SiFive\riscv-qemu-4.2.0-2020.04.0\bin\qemu-system-riscv64.exe: -readconfig bsp\qemu-sifive-s51\qemu.cfg: read config bsp\qemu-sifive-s51\qemu.cfg: No such file or directory
```

However, I can find this file in the exact folder indicated, with the following address:

```
C:\[...]\freedomstudio\SiFive\freedom-e-sdk-v20.05.00.02\bsp\qemu-sifive-s51\qemu.cfg
```

Is this the wrong bsp folder? Should there be something under SiFive\riscv-qemu-4.2.0-2020.04.0 instead of SiFive\freedom-e-sdk-v20.05.00.02? I double checked the "Let's Get Started" menu in case I disabled something to do with QEMU, and I've tried to debug multiple default Hello projects with the following settings:

[image]

Redownloading/reinstalling QEMU and Freedom Studio did not solve this error. Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: The filename in the error message is a relative path, so that suggests that this SDK/IDE isn't starting QEMU from the correct current working directory to let it find the file. Anyway, it looks like an issue with the IDE rather than with QEMU itself.